# How to implement Auth0 server-side with Nuxtjs?

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, auth0, server-side-rendering

I have a Nuxt app with authentication already running in universal mode.

I'm trying to convert the authentication service to Auth0. I'm following the [Vue quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs), but I discovered that [auth0-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auth0-js) is a client side library since it uses a lot of 'window'-stuff that is not available on the server-side of Nuxt.

However, I got it kind of working by making it a client-side plugin and wrap all functions (that is calling the authservice in the lifecycle hooks) in a `process.client` check. It works "kind of" because when going to the protected page whilst not logged in, it flashes the page before being redirected to login page (since its rendered on the server-side as well, but the check only happens once it's delivered on the client side I presume).

My question now is: 
**What can I do in order to add the check to server-side as well?** (or at least make sure that the protected pages isn't flashed before being redirected).

What I've tried so far:

- Saving the payload and the logged-in state in the store and check in some custom middleware, but that didn't do the trick.

*Also, it seems to me that @nuxt/auth is outdated or something and the [nuxt auth0 example](https://github.com/nuxt/example-auth0) as well. It uses auth0-lock while I'm using the new auth0 universal.*

Anyone have suggestions on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this will be any help and have only answered a few questions (other account long time ago).

---

**Update**.. I read my answer then the question title (I think my answer does cover some of your context), but in regards to the title you could also look at using `auth` as a [plugin](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/recipes/extend.html). You can then handle stuff there before the page is hit.

---

I am not sure how your code is implemented, but this may help (hopefully).

If you are not using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org), I strong recommend it. [Nuxt Vuex Store Guide](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store)

```js
// index/store.js
// At least have the store initialized, but its most likely going to be used..
```

```js
// page.vue
<template>
...
<div v-else-if="!$auth.loggedIn">
  {{ test }}
</div>
...
...

data() {
  if (!this.$auth.loggedIn) {
    const test = 'Only this will load, no flash'
    return { test }
  }
}
```

*`$auth.loggedIn` is built in, I read it ..somewhere.. in the docs*

This will solve the no flash issue, you can also take advantage of a loader screen and asyncData to check the `state` before rendering the view to avoid a flash and populate data if it hangs.

You could also try using **Vuex Actions**, I am currently playing with these 2 in the process of where I am now. Learning about [nuxtServerInit()](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action)

```js
// store/index.js
import axios from 'axios'

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit ({commit}, {request}) {
    // This is good if you have the user in your request or other server side stuff
    if (request.user) commit('SET_USER', request.user)
  },
  async GET_USER({ commit }, username) {
    const user = await axios.get(`/user/${username}`)
    if (user) commit('SET_USER', user)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    // simple set for now
    state.auth.user = user || null
  }
}
```

The second one is combined using the `fetch()` method on the page itself.

```js
// page.vue
async fetch({ $auth, store }) {
  await store.dispatch('GET_USER', $auth.$state.user)
}
```

Now you can call `$auth.user` in your code as needed.

*`$auth.user` is another built in I read ..somewhere..*

You can also call `$auth.user` with the `$auth.loggedIn` to check if `user` exists on top of being logged in `$auth.user && $auth.loggedIn`.

*It may be `this.$auth.<value>` depending on where you are trying to reference it.*

I learned the `asyncData()` gets call first and logs in my server, then `data()` logs values in the server console as well (`false`, `null`), but in my Brave console they're `undefined`, i'd like an answer to that lol

I have been struggling with trying to get `Auth0` to work how I wanted with **JWTs**, but as I kept crawling I found useful bits along the way (even in old demos such as the one you mentioned, just nothing with the `lock` stuff...). Also in terms of `express` and my **API** in general... Anyways, hope this helped (someone).